# Jquery UI doesn't seem to be loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website that has been using background color animations for a while when all of sudden they just stopped working. I can't think of any major change I've done that would have caused it. So I created a folder to test out my jquery.min.js and jquery.ui.js files. Here is the code:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/testing.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Template 3</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include('parts/welcomeSection.php');
?>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/animate.js"></script>
</html>
```

**testing.css**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
div#testing{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;    
}
```

**welcomeSection.php**

```
<div id="testing">

</div>
```

**animate.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    color = 'red';
    window.setInterval(function(){
        if(color == 'red'){
            $('div#testing').animate({'background-color': 'blue'}, 'fast', 'easeOutQuint'); 
            color = 'blue';
        }
        else if(color == 'blue'){
            $('div#testing').animate({'background-color': 'red'}, 'fast', 'easeOutQuint');  
            color = 'red';
        }
        console.log(color);
    }, 5000);
});
```

One thing to note is that the console is logging the color change every time. But the background-color is not changing. Instead I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: na.easing[this.easing] is not a function
```

This is not only for background color, it's also not working on a border-color animation either. Plus it does not recognize 'easeOutQuint'. All of this leads to believe that something is wrong between Jquery and Jquery UI. I tried downloading the Jquery and Jquery UI files again but this did not fix the problem.

Normal Jquery animations such as a marginLeft animation work just fine.

## Update:

I've found that this a problem only with Chrome. While browsing the internet I have had kinks in websites that use JQuery. But they work just fine in other browsers such as Microsoft Edge. Is this a problem with my Chrome?

Comment: why don't you try to achieve this using CSS transitions or simple CSS animation?

Comment: I could in this example, but it would be more complex than necessary for my other web page. Plus I would like to know what's going on with JQuery UI because I tend to use it very often.

Comment: well, considering web-design fundamentals and user bandwidth profile, I would avoid using external libraries on simple tasks like this one, you may achieve those kind of effects in a more stylish and light way

Comment: I 100% understand that. I only used this  example to show my problem. Without using Jquery and Jquery UI on my Web page I'd be going through WAY more hassle than what is necessary for generally the same effect.

Comment: try including all your scripts (lquery, ui, main script) before closing body tag, also as a small remark you should always keep your meta tags on top of the head of the doc, cause those are ones to give your users' browsers basic info about your document

Comment: Same result. I will keep the meta tag positioning in mind

Answer (score 0):

Change `background-color` to `backgroundColor`

also make sure your *jquery-ui.js* contains **jquery easing**s

Comment: I changed "background-color" to "backgroundColor" and received the same result. I also custom downloaded Jquery UI making sure every option was ticked

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. It seemed my local version of Chrome was doing something funky. So I reinstalled Chrome and the code works fine. It seemed to only not work with Chrome.